# Difference between Age of Empires 2 HD and the original Age of Empires 2

Tags: version-differences, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, age-of-empires-ii-hd

Are there any differences between the original Age of Empires 2 game and the HD remake? If so, what are they?

Comment: Multiplayer has been completely remade (for steam). For example, LAN play isn't possible anymore.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are differences between the two games, but they are mainly graphical or Steam-related. As stated on Wikipedia:

> The HD Edition includes both the original game and the expansion The Conquerors, as well as updated graphics for high-resolution displays. It also supports user-generated content through the Steam Workshop and multiplayer games provided through the Steam servers.

There are three paid [expansions](http://store.steampowered.com/dlc/221380), The Forgotten, The African Kingdoms and Rise of the Rajas which are exclusive to this version of the game.

It's also important to note that a team keeps working on patching the HD version of the game. While it would be ridiculously long to enumerate all those changes here, we can at least say they cover a lot of different points: upgrading performances and rendering, fixing bugs, balancing the units, upgrading the AIs and other convenient points. We can for instance quote [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296276/136461) where we have been talking about the possibility to move a greater amount of units comparing to the original version of the game.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Empires_II)

Comment: I believe a version of the Forgotten is available as a mod for the original Age of Empires 2 game

Comment: Also: The HD version uses the latest patch (1.0c) for the games, whereas the original games were slightly different.

Comment: Actually, there's numerous minor differences between the two versions. Many of Spirit of the Law's youtube videos explain them. Example @ 12:55 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdoyijRv54k

Comment: What exactly are the "graphical differences"? From the screenshots I've seen the artwork looks identical, the only difference that is immediately obvious is the support for higher screen resolutions by way of increasing the 2D camera's view area.

Comment: @Dai The fire and water are a good example of graphical differences.

Comment: Also, the HD edition fails real bad with co-op play

Comment: @mixxiphoid Oh now I notice that! HD looks a lot better graphics wise.

Comment: The HD version continues to be patched with fixes and balance changes. At this time, I believe [4.6](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/1/492379439669872458/) is the latest patch. [4.4](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/1/496880503063315751/) was the last to have significant balance improvements.

Comment: You should update this answer. There has been hundreds of balance and bug fixesin the HD edition: https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/announcements/

Comment: @user598527 Answer updated. :)