# Can you move more units at once in Age of Empires II HD than in the original version?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, age-of-empires-ii-hd

In the original Age of Empires II I built armies with more units than the game allows to move at once (40), even in the early campaign missions. Has this limit been increased in the HD version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original game, you can only move up to 40 units.

In the HD version of the game, this number has indeed been updated. You can select and move up to 60 units at the same time. It used to be 200 in the [public beta of the 2.4 patch](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/1/864971287466462385/), but it has been quickly lowered to 60. There is no real explanation for that, but main suspicions is about path finding being too complicated to calculate, while other think it could be because of the game balance itself.

Comment: Why was the limit lowered? Performance reasons or online multiplayer performance perhaps?

Comment: I edited the answer about this point. Basically, there was no real explanation, but people suspect it could be because of the path finding calculation or about the game balance (being able to move too much units at the same time would be unfair).

Comment: I think it might be due to the lack of icon space in the UI resulting in players not being able to accurately select a single unit from a selection group of 200 that they decided to make it 60 so all icons of units can be clearly seen and selected from a full control group - my opinion.